# Aligning nav with logo using relative positioning

Tags: html, css

My CSS positioning skills have always been truly terrible. I'm looking to place my nav bar next to my logo, as well as making it move with the page and not get all screwy on anything smaller than a maximized window on a 1080p screen.

What it currently looks like: http://5.9.78.201/abellant/

It will likely look odd if you're on a different screen size.

I've (so far) used methods found on here, to no avail, using relative, absolute, and even clearing before giving up on it.

Can anyone show me where I'm screwing this up? I'm quite embarrassed by the fact that of all things, my positioning is just so bad.

Thank you.

Comment: You have static positioning on your elements (i.e. `margin-right: 515px;`, ), which will always be absolute and will look odd on different screen sizes other than the one you designed it on (`margin-right: 515px;`, will ruin the layout on a small iPhone display). You need to relatively position your elements using relative units of measure like `%` instead of `px`. This can be a daunting task which is why there are responsive CSS frameworks like Bootstrap

Comment: @zgood Yeah, I love Bootstrap for this kind of thing, but my reason for not using it this time is around is that'd I'd like to start doing some freelance development on the side, and with that, I really need to stop relying on Boostrap or other frameworks to save me for positioning, which really is the only concept I fail to grasp. Have to learn it at one point or another, probably should just do it now.

Comment: If you want to 'hand-roll' this, see the responsive design tutorial from Google I posted - https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/?hl=en

Comment: @AaronNewton I was referring to your comment when I replied to him, was actually just about to reply to yours. I'll be looking into this and giving it a shot shortly. Thanks.

Comment: @OpFor More power to you then. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/) is a good reference to CSS units of measure. You will also  probably need to use a healthy dose of `@media` queries. Responsive design also gets way more crazy with dynamic content... godspeed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to position your logo and navbar at the center of the page::
Set #header "display:inline-block", "height:auto" and "text-align: center;" and remove all the css you have added to #logo and #navigation

```
#header {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background: #f2f2f2;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-shadow: 0 1.5px 1px #777;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}
```

And if you want to set your logo and navigation side by side::

```
#header {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background: #f2f2f2;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-shadow: 0 1.5px 1px #777;
display: inline-block;
}

#logo {
float: left;
width: 50%;
}

#navigation {
float: right;
margin: 40px;
}
```

If you want to move your header section with page scroll. Set #header to "position:fixed".

Comment: I was looking to get the header to not get all jumbled up when resizing the page, rather than scrolling.

I had this at one point but it wasn't the exact effect I was looking for (bottom portion). They're next to each other, but farther apart. Another user linked some tutorials for this kind of thing, so I'm off to those. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1):

So part of the problem is that you have a fixed left and right margin. Remove the fixed left and right margin for #logo and #navigation and do something like the following in your CSS:

```
#header {
    margin: 0 auto; /* 0 px on top and bottom, auto on left and right => centered for a block element */
    width: 960px; /* You need a width that will accomodate the logo and nav */
}
```

To make this work at other sizes, you'll need to look into CSS3 breakpoints. Here is a tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/?hl=en

Comment: P.S. if you go through the responsive design tutorial, it will instruct you to use relative units rather than a fixed width with margin auto. The correct response to this is to go with the advice from the tutorial - my code only solves your immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solve your problem.

```
 .container {
     min-width: 500px;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
 }

#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#navigation {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you noticed that the logo and the menu are NOT perfectly center it's because your image has a small white space, if you could delete that space and replace the new image it will be PERFECTLY center :)